# Can't find table object name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have an application in classic ASP, and a database in SQL server 2005.

I transfer the database in SQL server express edition and I have one strange problem, I can see the tables in the database in this way:

information_Schema.dbo.test, so when I execute SQL command

```
select * From test
```

I get error that it can't find the table.

When I execute

```
select * From information_Schema.dbo.test
```

I do get results.

The problem is that my application is many many files and I can't rewrite the SQL commands.

Is there any way to find a solution in SQL without changing anything in my application?

Comment: Were this SQL Server proper, I'd check to see if my permissions for the account I am logging in are correct. You may also want to ensure your connection string is correct. Have you tried executing other types of queries using the connection string from SQL Server Express?

Comment: i think permissions are ok, have u got an example of connection string that can play with no problem?

Comment: http://www.dofactory.com/Connect/Connect.aspx, scroll down to Microsoft Sql Express.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you are not connecting to the information_Schema database but to some other db that does not contain the table. Did you put the table in the wrong place(Information_Schema doesn't sound like a typical application db location to me) or is your connection wrong?